# Why some tabs of my deployed shiny dashboard are displaying errors yet they are working smoothly on local computer?

Tags: r, twitter, shiny, shinyapps

I have built the interactive shiny dashboard to regular monitor the live tweets and underlying sentiments for different Twitter users. Fortunately, it is locally working as it is expected, but after being deployed on shinyapps.io, some of the tabs are not displaying the graphs (i.e probably the tweets are not automatically extracted). See the dashboard here (https://bnrdatascience.shinyapps.io/BNR_Tweets_Monitoring_Tool/).

```
#Registering the OAuth
  #_______________________________________
  #Save app credentials for access to tweets
  #consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  
  #consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  
  #accessToken <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  
  #accessTokenSecret <-  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  
  #set up 
  setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret_key,access_token,access_token_secret)
  
#1. Extracting the live tweets for sentiments analysis
#______________________
  dataInput <- reactive({
    data <- searchTwitter(input$Input_Hashtag, n = input$Tweets_to_Download, 
                          resultType = "recent", lang = "en")
    
    twListToDF(data)
  })
  #__________________________________
 
  #__________________________________
  #Create reactive word cloud
  output$wordcloud <- renderWordcloud2({
    ##Word clouds for all tweets
    table_1 <- dataInput() %>% 
      mutate(rowmumber = row_number()) %>% 
      mutate(text = tolower(text)) %>% 
      mutate(text = gsub("rt", "", text)) %>% 
      mutate(text = gsub("https","", text)) %>% 
      mutate(text = gsub("t.co", "", text)) %>% 
      mutate(text = removeNumbers(text)) %>% 
      mutate(text = gsub("coronoavirus", "coronavirus", text)) %>% 
      unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
      anti_join(stop_words) %>% 
      count(word, sort = T) 
    #WorldCloud materials:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html
    wordcloud2a <- function (data, size = 1, minSize = 0, gridSize = 0, fontFamily = "Segoe UI", 
                             fontWeight = "bold", color = "random-dark", backgroundColor = "white", 
                             minRotation = -pi/4, maxRotation = pi/4, shuffle = TRUE, rotateRatio = 0.4,
                             shape = "circle", ellipticity = 0.75, 
                             widgetsize = NULL, figPath = NULL, hoverFunction = NULL) #color="random-light"
    {
      if ("table" %in% class(data)) {
        dataOut = data.frame(name = names(data), freq = as.vector(data))
      }
      else {
        data = as.data.frame(data)
        dataOut = data[, 1:2]
        names(dataOut) = c("name", "freq")
      }
      if (!is.null(figPath)) {
        if (!file.exists(figPath)) {
          stop("cannot find fig in the figPath")
        }
        spPath = strsplit(figPath, "\\.")[[1]]
        len = length(spPath)
        figClass = spPath[len]
        if (!figClass %in% c("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp", "gif")) {
          stop("file should be a jpeg, jpg, png, bmp or gif file!")
        }
        base64 = base64enc::base64encode(figPath)
        base64 = paste0("data:image/", figClass, ";base64,", 
                        base64)
      }
      else {
        base64 = NULL
      }
      weightFactor = size * 180/max(dataOut$freq)
      settings <- list(word = dataOut$name, freq = dataOut$freq, 
                       fontFamily = fontFamily, fontWeight = fontWeight, color = color, 
                       minSize = minSize, weightFactor = weightFactor, backgroundColor = backgroundColor, 
                       gridSize = gridSize, minRotation = minRotation, maxRotation = maxRotation, 
                       shuffle = shuffle, rotateRatio = rotateRatio, shape = shape, 
                       ellipticity = ellipticity, figBase64 = base64, hover = htmlwidgets::JS(hoverFunction))
      chart = htmlwidgets::createWidget("wordcloud2", settings, 
                                        width = widgetsize[1], height = widgetsize[2], sizingPolicy = htmlwidgets::sizingPolicy(viewer.padding = 0, 
                                                                                                                                browser.padding = 0, browser.fill = TRUE))
      chart
    }
    
    wordcloud2a(table_1, size = 0.75, shape = "circle", ellipticity = 0.60)
  })
   
#2. Extracting the user information to show the Twitter account status
 Bankdata <- reactive({
    
    userdf <- lookup_users(input$Input_Hashtag)
    
    users_data(userdf)
  })
#3. Extracting the historic tweets for trend analysis
#___________________________________________________
 dataInput1 <- reactive({
    
    data <- get_timeline(input$Input_Hashtag, n=3500)
    
    as_tibble(data)
  })
```

In summary, The deployed app has issue with the second and third tweets extraction process.

Could anyone assist me  to figure out what happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your log on shinyapps.io? What does it say?

Comment: Thanks @Jan to reach out and here below is what Log says, Could you get something from log heading to solution.The warning error that is dominating logs is Warning: Error in readRDS: error reading from connection

Comment: Could it by any chance be that you have a free account?

Comment: Can you specify which tabs aren't displaying (I just took a look, and it looks great)